# how to use the solidity shift for non binary numbers?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, evm

I wanted to pop some zeros of a number without having to use division.(from 1000 to 10).
I checked out the operand << and i know it's only for bit shifts but I was wondering if there is a way I can use shift in solidity to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Everything solidity can do efficiently maps directly to an ethereum EVM op code (listed here: [evm.codes/](https://www.evm.codes/)). The only shift operations listed are for binary bits. If the goal is to save gas, then multiply or divide by ten inside an `unchecked` block (but be sure you won't have issues with underflow and overflow).